# Count number of rows in another list

Tags: lookup-column, calculated-column-formula

I have two lists, A and B. I wish to find out the number of rows in list B that have a certain value in list A (through a lookup column) and display this in list A.

Is this possible at all using a calculated field? Or how to best approach this?

Many thanks.